# Posts made to profile page via FB.ui feed dialog are getting posted but links are not working

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

Steps to Reproduce:

//Init Javascript SDK

```
FB.init({ 
    appId:'204874249538850', cookie:true, 
    status:false, xfbml:true, oauth:true 
});
```

//Create action links

```
var strActionLinks = '[{"name": "' + 'Listen'+ '", "link": "' + 'http://www.myusic.com/DailyPosts/Tina_Munim.html' + '"}]';
var action_links = JSON.parse(strActionLinks);
```

Then post on the wall of the profile page http://www.facebook.com/pages/Myusic/196053677086787

```
var obj = {method: 'feed', 
link: 'http://www.myusic.com/DailyPosts/Tina_Munim.html', 
picture: 'http://www.myusic.com/DailyPosts/Tina_Munim.jpg', 
name: 'Tina Munim', 
caption: 'Explore, Discover, Share...', 
description: 'Some description', 
actions: action_links, 
from: '196053677086787' 
}; 


FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

Expected Behavior:  The post should appear on the page. Clicking on the link should take the user to the web site

Actual Behavior:    The post appears on the page. But clicking on the link does nothing

Comment: PS - This was up and running till a few days ago...anything to do with OAUth2.0?

Answer (score 1):

In you app settings, on the authentication tab, is 'authenticated referrals' enabled? If yes, try turning this off.

This is a response from Simon Cross on a related issue reported on http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7699748/stream-story-links-not-clickable

Answer (score -1):

(This is not an answer, but i cannot post a comment):

I just posted the same problem. It started happening yesterday : http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7699748/stream-story-links-not-clickable

If you have a canvas app too, you can send the links there and do a redirect

Comment: thanks...yes,observed that the canvas links are working but external are not...even tried with https...a bit surprised...either we are doing something dramatically wrong or there would have been thousands of apps reporting the same issue!